# Is there a way in Python3 to dynamically build function argument names?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am searching for a tip/technique to dynamically build function argument names when calling a method:

I have a function which is using dynamic arguments that later are posted to a Webservice using http:

```
def create_case(**fields):
...
```

Currently, I call the function like this:

```
create_case(field54=first_name,
            field_1003=last_name,
            field_948=street)
```

Since I have multiple instances of the Webservices, which have different field ID's I try to put those argument names into a configuration file and build them dynamically. All my current tries were not successful and I ran out of ideas on how to approach this.

**What I tried:**

config.py:

```
FIELD_FIRST_NAME=54
FIELD_LAST_NAME=1003
FIELD_STREET=948
```

client.py:

```
create_case(field_+config.FIELD_FIRST_NAME=first_name,
            field_+config.FIELD_LAST_NAME=last_name,
            field_+config.FIELD_STREET=street)
```

It seems, it's not possible to just concat the arguments together. Does anyone have a suggestion on how I could go on this ?

Best regards

Comment: This might help, https://stackoverflow.com/a/36908/4985099

Comment: I think what you want (should do) is your function to take a dictionary as parameter.

Comment: You can create a dict in the form `{<"arg name">: <value>}` and pass it as `kwargs` to the func

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of the arguments:

```
kwargs_dict = {
    "field_"+str(config.FIELD_FIRST_NAME): first_name,
    "field_"+str(config.FIELD_LAST_NAME): last_name,
    "field_"+str(config.FIELD_STREET): street
}
```

and then pass this to the function as:

```
create_case(**kwargs_dict)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :-) This is a great solution